# Angular 5 event emitter triggered twice

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-event-emitter

I am using angular 5. In which I am passing data from one component to another component using eventemitter.

At first click event emitter is not subscribe the value in child component. On second click event emitter triggered twice.

Header component.ts

```
 this.testservice.sendsearchdata.next( this.searchdataform.value)
```

Search component.ts

```
this.testservice.sendsearchdata.subscribe(value=>{ 
    console.log( value)
})
```

testservice.ts

```
  public testservice: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter ():
```

While passing reactive form data from header component to search component it's not triggered at first click. On next click it has triggered twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are incorrectly using [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter). It's used when child component emitting events to parent component via @Output() property. In your case, component communication realized by using service. Try this way:

> ```
> @Injectable()
> export class MissionService {
>
>   // Observable string sources
>   private missionAnnouncedSource = new Subject<string>();
>   private missionConfirmedSource = new Subject<string>();
>
>   // Observable string streams
>   missionAnnounced$ = this.missionAnnouncedSource.asObservable();
>   missionConfirmed$ = this.missionConfirmedSource.asObservable();
>
>   // Service message commands
>   announceMission(mission: string) {
>     this.missionAnnouncedSource.next(mission);
>   }
>
>   confirmMission(astronaut: string) {
>     this.missionConfirmedSource.next(astronaut);
>   }
> }
> ```

[Parent and children communicate via a service](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service)

Answer (score 0):

My event emitter was bound to button click event. 
`<button class="signin-button btn-primary btn" (click)="submit()">Create Account</button>`

By switching the button input to an a tag.
`<a class="signin-button btn-primary btn" (click)="submit()">Create Account</a>`

It stopped triggering more than one event.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not specify any type (or type="submit") in a form it causes double EventEmitter instead single so you must specify type="button" like:

```
 <button type="button" (click)="emitMe()">
 </button>
```